# Experiment by using a Matlab's demo data set and publish to journal/conference

Tags: data

I hope my question is within the topic of this forum.

I would like to test an algorithm to a real application data and publish in a journal/conference. However, I cannot acquired my own data set myself and I am thinking to use one of Matlab's demos data set that is mentioned from a real experiment.

Is it acceptable to use those data set for a conference/journal publication?

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking whether the license to the Matlab software allows you to publish work based on their data set? If so, what does the license say? Or are you asking whether this is valid from a scientific perspective (we can't possibly answer that, since we don't know your research)?

Comment: I did not think of your first question, but my question is the second: the validity from a scientific perspective. 
I am doing system identification research

Comment: Well, we don't know anything about the research or the dataset, so it's not really possible to judge. The fact that it's a Matlab data set is not relevant; the question is whether it's an appropriate data set for *your* research, and that is out of scope of this site.

Comment: After rethinking my question, I think I have asked an out of scope question. I am sorry

Comment: If the data is "real" (you mention that it comes from a real experiment) and it's stated where it comes from, you should try to find the original source of the data (research paper, report etc) and refer to that instead of referring to "Matlab demo data". The question about suitability for your application etc that @ff524 mentions is still valid though.

Comment: Using widely available data sets is certainly useful, so others can check your results or compare other approaches.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternate suggestion, you might try calling people who either do similar research, or are involved in the application the research covers, and get a copy of their data. I've never done it at a publishing level, and I don't know what kind of field you're in, but I have had success with this for some minor projects I've done.

Generally, it's not in the exact format you want, but real data is better than suspicious data. And reformatting is a lot easier than collecting tons of data.